# Bootstrap Grid - How to choose?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, 960.gs, grid-system

my first post here,

I´m designing a layout in photoshop and i know that it´s important to have a layer where i have my grid to design the elements according with that.

I searched on the web psd´s to download and use on my design and im super confused.
So i just like to know which criteria i have to consider to choose a bootstrap grid system.

Aspects to solve that makes me confuse:

- Which Bootstrap version should i choose? And based on what?
- Number of columns? And based on what?
- Which gutter size should I choose? Based on What?

Please help me to solve this, i keep seeing millions of different bootstrap grid system and i just dont know how to choose.

Thanks everyone

Comment: There is only one "Bootstrap" grid system. Are you talking about a custom build of Bootstrap, customizing the grid with LESS/SASS or using another responsive grid system (ie: skeleton, pureCSS)?

Answer (score 1):

The simple straight answer is ... "**It completely depends on your requirements**".

You cannot just choose the Bootstrap grid system. You obviously need to first understand what exactly is Bootstrap and how does the BS grid work, otherwise this question is very vague.

[Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-grid-system/) is a good tutorial.

Take an hour to read through it well and most importantly ... **practice with hands on coding simultaneously** !

There are good online bootstrap editors like [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) where you can code experiment side by side.

**Which version ?**

Always get the **latest stable** version according to me(as of now its v3.3.6). You can also check out the latest Bootstrap 4 alpha version [here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/)